# How to add post api request in parameters while parsing in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, parameter-passing

This is my api request:

```
{
"billDetails": {
           "billerId":"EPDCLOB00AN232",
            "customerParams":[{"name":"Service Number","value":"116515M025033"}]
             }
}
```

here is code:

```
func billerFetchService(){

let parameters = ["billDetails": {
    "billerId" : "EPDCLOB00ANP01",
    "customerParams" : [{"name":"Service Number","value":"116515M025007621"}]
                                 }
                  ] as [String : Any]


let url = URL(string: "https://app.com/Fetch/fetch")
var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
req.httpMethod = "POST"
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
req.httpBody = httpBody
let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if response != nil {
        // print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {
        do{
            var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
            print("fetching json \(json)")

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
}).resume()
}
```

if i add like this in `parameters` error

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
>    Insert ';'
>    Expected expression

Where i did mistake, please help me in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
let parameters = ["billDetails": [
    "billerId" : "EPDCLOB00ANP01",
    "customerParams" : [["name":"Service Number","value":"116515M025007621"]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make your parameter as this

```
 let parameters = ["billDetails":
         [
          "billerId": "EPDCLOB00ANP01",
         "customerParams" : ["name":"Service Number","value":"116515M025007621"]
        ]
        ] as [String : Any]
```